# Docusaurus build fails with "sharp" module issue

Tags: build, node-modules, sharp, docusaurus

Upon `yarn build` my projects fails to build. I've tried recommended options, but nothing works and error returns every-time. The project works upon using `yarn start`, just the `build` doesn't work

```
[ERROR] Unable to build website for locale en.
[ERROR] Error: 
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-darwin-x64.node'
Require stack:
- /Users/.../node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/@docusaurus/responsive-loader/lib/adapters/sharp.js
- /Users/..../node_modules/@docusaurus/responsive-loader/sharp.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/@docusaurus/plugin-ideal-image/lib/index.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/plugins/init.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/plugins/index.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/index.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/commands/build.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/.../node_modules/@docusaurus/core/bin/docusaurus.js
 
Possible solutions:
- Install with the --verbose flag and look for errors: "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp"
- Install for the current runtime: "npm install --platform=darwin --arch=x64 sharp"
- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
```

Comment: Fixed by reinstalling `node_modules`

Comment: Hi Fill, I am having the same issue but reinstalling did not work for me. did you delete your node modules before you reinstalled them?

Comment: @mamadoujallow I've deleted the folder then reinstalled it with `npm install`